# Limit count of elements in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have div with questions

Here is it
[image]

Here is code for it

```
<div class="listdivright">
        <div style="height: 80%; width: 100%; overflow: auto">

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                   <div class="title" style="margin-top:15px;margin-left:15px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                       <img class="click"   src="@Url.Content("~/Images/plus_plus.png")" />
                        <span>
                           @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.question, new {@class="testclass", @readonly = "readonly" })
                         </span>

                       <a class="click2"  style="margin-left:10px;">
                           <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/arrow.png")' />
                       </a>
                       <a style="margin-left:25px;" href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Questions", new {id = item.QuestionId})'>
                           <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")' />
                       </a>
                       <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Questions", new {id = item.QuestionId})'>
                           <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")' />
                       </a>
                   </div>
                   <div class="content" style="margin-left:60px; width: 80%; height: 100px; background: white">
                        <div style="width: 100%">
                            <div style="float:left; width: 50%;">
                                <b>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem=>item.TimeForAnswer)</b>
                                <b>:</b>
                                <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.TimeForAnswer)</span>
                            </div>
                            <div style="float:right;width: 50%;">
                                <b>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.TimeForReady)</b>
                                <b>:</b>
                                <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeForReady)</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;" >
                           <b>@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Retries)</b>
                           <b>:</b>
                           <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Retries)</b>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                }

        </div>
```

I use JS to move block to left div

Code of JS script

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('.title').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
$('.click2').click(function () {
    var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
    $('.title2').append($(elem).html()).show();

});
```

Here is code of left div

```
<div class="listdivleft">
        <div style="height: 80%; width: 100%; overflow: auto">
           <div class="title2" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 15px; margin-bottom: 15px;padding-top: 10px">
                </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

I need to limit blocks in left div. From 0 to 10.

So it can be 0 or not more than 10

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that if element with class `title` are less than 10 using [`length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) property, in that case only the new html should be appended, something like:

```
 if($(".title").length < 10) {
    var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
    $('.title2').append($(elem).html()).show();
 }
 else {
    alert("No more than 10 allowed.");
 }
```

or if title class is reused other places as well on page, then restrict it to current parent element using **listdivright** class element in combination with [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) :

```
if($(this).closest(".listdivright").find(".title").length < 10) {
    var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
    $('.title2').append($(elem).html()).show();
 }
 else {
    alert("No more than 10 allowed.");
 }
```

Hope it helps and gives you idea how it can be done.

Comment: Elegant ... a Link to the jquery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/length/) would add to the beauty of the answer :)

Comment: added on your wish :)

Comment: Not works.

I write it like this
`<script type="text/javascript" >
    $('.title').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
    if ($(this).closest(".listdivright").find(".title").length < 10) {
        var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
        $('.title2').append($(elem).html()).show();
    }
    else {
        alert("No more than 10 allowed.");
    }
    $('.click2').click(function () {
        var elem = $(this).closest('.title');
        $('.title2').append($(elem).html()).show();
        
    });
</script>`

Comment: you need to check the conosle to see if any errors came, answer should give you idea how to do, it is not necessary that just copy pasting it will work for you, you might need to tweak a little bit

Comment: then try debugging the click event code to see what is going wrong

Comment: It works, but when I click again it alert and add new element